# Filter out rows of panda-df by comparing to list

Tags: python, pandas

The following problem occurs often. Say I have a dataframe, where one column can take a discrete value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7], 'col2': ["A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "D"]})
```

In this case `col2` can take values A, B or C. I only want to rows where `col2` **is not** equal to A or B. I thought the following syntax would work,

```
df["col2"] not in ["A", "B"]
```

However, this gives me the error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Is there a neat way to filter those rows out?

Comment: You want `df[~df['col2'].isin(['A','B'])]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `isin` method.

```
df = df[~df.col2.isin(['A', 'B'])]
```

Output

```
   col1 col2
3     4    C
6     7    D
```

Comment: this is a dupe, not necessary to answer IMO, also didn't downvote